# Stepper motor control using siemens s71200 plc

Tags: stepper-motor, plc

I am doing a project in which i want to run a conveyor belt using a stepper motor, through a siemens s71200 plc.Can anyone help me in doing so.

Comment: Is there something in particular you need help with? I doubt there are many people on here willing to do the whole project for you...

Answer (score 1):

How big is the stepper motor?  Do you already have a stepper motor driver?

If your stepper motor is small enough (fractional-horsepower), a suitable stepper driver board that might drive it is available from [GeckoDrive](http://www.geckodrive.com).  I'm thinking of something the GM215 Step Motor / Motion Controller - this unit is rated at 80V 7A max and the suggested motor size is up to Nema 42.

The reason I make this suggestion is that it requires only two control lines from your system controller: step & direction.  This does presume that your controller can generate step pulses fast enough - most PLCs have that capability.